# Spring security - how to mention both form based and basic authentication

Tags: spring-security

Is it possible to mention both form-based and basic authentication in Spring security using namespace configuration without overriding other ? So that the appliciation could serve both browser based request and remoting client.

Answer (score 10):

The [response by @grimesjm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297243/spring-security-how-to-mention-both-form-based-and-basic-authentication/1689912#1689912) is right.  However, if you are using Spring 3.x you have to adapt the class names to:

```
<bean id="basicProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref bean="authenticationManager" />
    </property> 
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <ref bean="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Your realm here" />
</bean>
```

And

```
<sec:http auto-config="true">
    ... your intercept-url here

    <sec:custom-filter before="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="basicProcessingFilter" />

    <sec:form-login ... />
    ....
</sec:http>
```

I do not know whether placing the filter before `SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER` is the best option or not.

Answer (score 6):

The end result you want is possible, I have ran into that exact same problem and here is my solution.

Anytime when defining form-login in the namespace it will override automatically any other authentication filters you apply via namespace. This is done through the ordering of the filter chain look at FilterChainOrder.java in the spring security to see how the order is actually applied to each filter.

To get around this remove the http-basic tag from the namespace then manually define the bean to handle basic authentication and place its order before the AuthenticationProcessingFilter because this is the spring security filter that will handle the form-login.

The BasicProcessingFilter spring provides to handle Basic authentication is a passive filter, meaning that if the credentials are missing it will continue down the filter chain until it finds the appropriate filter to handle the request.

Now by manually defining the BasicProcessingFilter bean we can set the order that it will appear in the filter chain. 
Below is an example of the additional xml declarations you will need to supply in the security xml (Spring Security < 3.x)

```
<bean id="basicProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager"><ref bean="authenticationManager"/></property>
     <security:custom-filter before="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER"/>
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint"><ref bean="authenticationEntryPoint"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
              <property name="realmName" value="My Realm Here"/>
</bean>
```

Also note if your authenticationManager reference isn't found you can add an alias to your namespace like the one below.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>
```

The end result is the basic filter will be applied as a passive filter and if its required credentials are missing it will continue down the filter chain and the form-login filter will then handle it.

The problem with this approach is that if credentials are correctly entered, the response back is the login page from the form-login filter.

However, It appears that this problem will be fixed by spring in version 3.1 of spring security and this work around will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible with Spring Security 3.1.0

Comment: This is correct, here is a link that will expand on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671861/two-realms-in-same-application-with-spring-security

Comment: I think the goal is to have the REST API support both authentications within the same realm. Defining two realms is like defining two wars - it works but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to declare both form and basic authentication using namespace configuration.

A reference link to spring community :
 http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=72724&highlight=form+basic+authentication

Comment: They added the possibility to add multiple <security:http configs, in Spring Security version 3.1.0.M1... which is not yet released. An other workaround is to create a separate war. In my case, we have a web application (form based auth) and an rest api (basic auth). I created a core, a web and a rest maven module. In the end this a even clean solution I find.