# Two realms in same application with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

We're building a web application that is available to both authenticated and anonymous users. If you decide not to register/login you only have a limited set of features. User authentication is done over OpenID with Spring Security. That works fine.

However, the application also comes with an admin UI that is deployed at `<host>/<context-root>/admin`. Can we have two separate realms with Spring Security (e.g. basic auth for `/admin/**`)? How does that have to be configured?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spring Security has added support for this scenario in version 3.1, which is currently available as a Release Candidate. It was implemented by [SEC-1171](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1171) and details of the syntax are in the manual included with 3.1.

However it's pretty simple to use. Basically you just define multiple `http` elements in your Spring Security configuration, one for each realm. We're using it like this:

```
<!-- Configure realm for system administration users -->
<security:http pattern="/admin/**" create-session="stateless">
    <security:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN' requires-channel="https" />
    <security:http-basic/>  
</security:http>


<!-- Configure realm for standard users -->
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/error/noaccess" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            ...
            ...
</security:http>
```

The key thing to note is the `pattern="/admin/**"` on the first `http` element. This tells Spring that all URLs under `/admin` are subject to that realm instead of the default realm — and thus URLs under `/admin` use basic authentication instead.

Comment: I've been digging all over trying to figure out how to do exactly this, thanks for pointing it out so clearly!

Comment: Spring security 3.1.0 has been officially released on 7/12/2011

Comment: I'm doing exactly this and if I'm logged to admin section I'm also logged into user section but not authorized (of course). I think this is because spring security holds authorization in session under one key. Is there a way to configure spring security to scenario where you can be logged to admin and user section on same time with different authorization entity?

Comment: looks like the syntax for access attribute is wrong should be: access="hasRole('ROLE_name')"

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

- Add URL interceptor for `/admin` the requires "ROLE_ADMIN"
- Configure instance of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter` to intercept the `/admin` URL and authenticate user as ROLE_ADMIN if it provides the appropriate credentials

Sample configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

<bean id="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" 
              value="WS realm"/>
</bean>

<bean id="basicAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" 
              ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" 
              ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>    
</bean>
```

Note: default implementation of BasicAuthenticationFilter is a passive filter, i.e. it just looks for a basic auth header in the request and if it is not present - does nothing. If you want the filter to explicitly require the basic authentication from the client, you need to extend the default implementation to commence to authentication entry point:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationFilter 
       extends org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if ((header != null) && header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
        } else {
            getAuthenticationEntryPoint().commence(request, response, new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Missing credentials"));
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, you need to tweak the filter to apply to `/admin` URL only - either by hard-coding this in `doFilter` method or by providing an appropriate wrapper bean.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a straight forward way to have two realms (and I didn't try it myself):

you may define two filters [in your web.xml](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-web-xml) where each of those has a different spring configuration and ergo an own environment. The global things go into the app config, the realm-specific in the filter config.

if it's only for a different auth method, you could [write your own filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) which then decides which filter to call.