# How to secure a web application with multiple realms using Spring's Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a web application with 2 types of resources.

- web pages
- web services

I want to secure the web pages using one authentication provider (i.e. CAS) and the web services using another authentication provider (i.e. BASIC authentication).

I found a solution which could work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671861/two-realms-in-same-application-with-spring-security), but it uses XML, and I would prefer to not use XML configuration if possible.

Is there a Java Config solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Well it took a while to figure out how to do it...

Basically I split up my original security configuration class into 3 separate configuration classes.

This is basically how I did it...

The main security configuration...

```
@Configuration
@Import({WebPageSecurityConfig.class, WebServiceSecurityConfig.class})
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

The security configuration for web pages... (URL does not begin with /service/**)

```
@Configuration
@Order(200)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebPageSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.requestMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(final HttpServletRequest request) {
                final String url = request.getServletPath() + StringUtils.defaultString(request.getPathInfo());
                return !(url.startsWith("/service/"));
            }
 });
        http.addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter()).exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        http.authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/securedPage").hasAuthority("ROLE_CAS_USER"). // /securedPage can only be accessed by cas user
            anyRequest().permitAll(); // all other pages are unsecured
    }

    // General Application Security (CAS Authentication)

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        final CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("cas.server.url") + "/login");
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(casServiceProperties());
        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties casServiceProperties() {
        final ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(env.getRequiredProperty("cas.service.url") + "/j_spring_cas_security_check");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        final CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(casAuthenticationUserDetailsService());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(casServiceProperties());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(casTicketValidator());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("casAuthenticationProviderKey");
        casAuthenticationProvider.setStatelessTicketCache(casStatelessTicketCache());
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService casAuthenticationUserDetailsService() {
        final AbstractCasAssertionUserDetailsService authenticationUserDetailsService = new AbstractCasAssertionUserDetailsService() {

            @Override
            protected UserDetails loadUserDetails(final Assertion assertion) {
                final String username = assertion.getPrincipal().getName();
                final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CAS_USER"));                
                return new User(username, "notused", authorities);
            }
        };

        return authenticationUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TicketValidator casTicketValidator() {
        final Saml11TicketValidator ticketValidator = new Saml11TicketValidator(env.getRequiredProperty("cas.server.url"));
        ticketValidator.setTolerance(env.getRequiredProperty("cas.ticket.tolerance", Long.class));
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public StatelessTicketCache casStatelessTicketCache() {
        final EhCacheBasedTicketCache ticketCache =  new EhCacheBasedTicketCache();
        ticketCache.setCache(casCache());
        return ticketCache;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "initialise", destroyMethod = "dispose")
    public Cache casCache() {
        final Cache cache = new Cache("casTickets", 50, true, false, 3600, 900);
        return cache;
    }       

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
}
```

The security configuration for RESTful web services (URL starts with /service/**)

```
@Configuration
@Order(300)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebServiceSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
            withUser("admin").password("password").authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_WS_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.
            antMatcher("/service/**"). // only process URLs that begin with /service/
            sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and(). // RESTful web services are stateless
            addFilter(wsAuthenticationFilter()).exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(wsAuthenticationEntryPoint());

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_WS_USER"); // all requests are secured
    }

    // Web Service Security (BASIC Authentication)

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthenticationFilter wsAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final BasicAuthenticationFilter wsAuthenticationFilter = new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), wsAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        return wsAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint wsAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        final BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint wsAuthenticationEntryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        wsAuthenticationEntryPoint.setRealmName("My Realm");
        return wsAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's explain how to create multiple securities in the docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity

something like this should work

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Resource private UserDetailsService userBasicAuthService;

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .userDetailsService(userBasicAuthService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class PagesWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Resource private UserDetailsService userCasService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/pages/**")
                .userDetailsService(userCasService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).