# Two login pages but wrong redirects in spring app

Tags: spring, http, spring-security

I'm trying to create an other login page on my application.
The second one is working properly but the first one I just added don't catch the URL correctly and don't redirect to the good page.
The second HTTP configurations is always use.

```
<security:http pattern="/vcrequest/**" use-expressions="true" realm="NETMG Spring Security" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
     <security:logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />

     <security:form-login
        login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/vcrequest/view/loginVCR"
        default-target-url="/vcrequest/controller/vcrequest/my-request"
        authentication-failure-url="/vcrequest/view/loginVCR?login_error=t" />

     <security:intercept-url pattern="/vcrequest/view/loginVCR" access="permitAll" />   
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/vcrequest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
     <security:http-basic/>
 </security:http>

<security:http use-expressions="true" realm="NETMG Spring Security" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />

     <security:form-login
        login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/view/login"
        default-target-url="/view/home#agregateShowMode=site"
        authentication-failure-url="/view/login?login_error=t" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD_USERS')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/export/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_EXPORT')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/stocks/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_STOCKS')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/site/edit/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_SITE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/site/create*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD_SITE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/site/save*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_SITE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/site/change*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLOSE_SITE')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/add/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD_SERVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/add*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD_SERVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/link/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_LINK_SERVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/edit/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_SERVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/save/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_SERVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/service/close/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLOSE_SERVICE')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/link/add/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADD_LINK', 'ROLE_ADD_LINK_FOR_REQUEST')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/link/link*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD_LINK')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/link/edit/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_LINK')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/link/save/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_LINK')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/link/close/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLOSE_LINK')" />


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/add/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADD_DEVICE', 'ROLE_ADD_DEVICE_FOR_REQUEST')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/link/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_LINK_DEVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/link*" access="hasRole('ROLE_LINK_DEVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/edit/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_DEVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/save/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDIT_DEVICE')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/controller/home/device/close/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLOSE_DEVICE')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/private/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- URLs not secured -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/view/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/view/loginVCR" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jamon/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/view/js-dynamic/**" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- All others URLs need at least that the user is authenticated -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

I use the following post but without success :
[Two realms in same application with Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671861/two-realms-in-same-application-with-spring-security)
Does anyone know how to solve the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe having the same login-processing-url on both realms is making the trouble. Have you tried changing first realms login-processing-url to another mapping, such as for example:

```
<security:form-login
        login-processing-url="/anotherresource/j_spring_security_check"
```

Note: in case you set this parameter to a first realm matching pattern, as

```
/vcrequest/j_spring_security_check
```

remember to bypass it in security realm with

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/vcrequest/j_spring_security_check"` access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm gonna try your solution that seems to be a good one