# Spring Security 3.x: How can I enable both BASIC and DIGEST authentication?

Tags: spring-security

I want to configure Spring Security to enable both BASIC and DIGEST authentication for the same set of URL's, but it's unclear whether or not this is possible. I see that I need to enable multiple `AuthenticationEntryPoint` instances to set the appropriate HTTP headers, but I don't see any built in classes to accomodate this. [`DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) comes close, but ultimately it only selects one entry point.

I implemented a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that calls the commence method on a supplied list of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` instances, but it eventually throws an `IllegalStateException` because each `AuthenticationEntryPoint` calls sendError (which I gather is not allowed).

Is there any way to do this without implementing a completely custom entry point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id did it by configuring Spring security for Digest authentication only, and then adding a BasicProcessingFilter  manually at the beginning of the filter chain, as explained [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297243/spring-security-how-to-mention-both-form-based-and-basic-authentication)

```
<bean id="basicProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter">
<property name="authenticationManager"><ref bean="authenticationManager"/></property>
 <security:custom-filter before="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER"/>
<property name="authenticationEntryPoint"><ref bean="authenticationEntryPoint"/></property>
```

Comment: So how does this solve the issue of the multiple entry points. I looks like the filter is added to the chain, but the only entry point responsible with commencing authentication is the DigestgAuthenticationEntryPoint? Thanks.