# Spring security: Adding a new ROLE which supports authentication by IP

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm a reasonably new user of Spring Security.

I previously configured Spring Security to perform form based authentication for my web app.

I've used Annotations to indication which Controllers/Methods require ROLE_USER vs anonymous, and implemented my own daoAuthenticationProvider to perform the authentication.

I am **now implementing REST** services which need to authentication on BasicAuthentication + do an IP verification to my DB.

So I have a new role ROLE_IP_AUTH which I've defined on the REST services controller.

I'm just a little overwhelmed at this point. Can someone give me a brief description of what next step I should take?

- Do I need to create a new
  <security:http> element for the new
  role?
- Should I be switching to this
  FilterChainProxy? If so what filters
  should I include?
- Should I just handle this in my existing daoAuthenticationProvider class?

Basically I just need to know what direction I'm going in. I think I know enough to get there, there's just 5 different ways to get anywhere in Spring it seems.

---

**Additional Information**
My current implementation has the  element configured as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config="false"
               entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER" ref="anonymousAuthFilter" />
</security:http>
```

My remaining question is how I can implement my own IP validation. I can just add the BasicAuth filter using custom-filter and implement my own basic auth filter which checks the IP. But I'm fuzzy on how I make that filter only applicable for the ROLE_IP_AUTH being used by my REST services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Ritesh has been very helpful in re-framing this questing in a different way. Another great post that addresses this question is here:

[Spring security - how to mention both form based and basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297243/spring-security-how-to-mention-both-form-based-and-basic-authentication)

Ultimately my understanding is: do it via voters as @Ritesh suggests in 3.0.x, or use multiple <http ... /> elements as is now available in 3.1.0.RC1 (version as of 17mar2011) as discussed in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add http-basic to your  element.

```
<sec:http-basic/>
```

Also add create-session="never" cause you do not add a session for a REST service. Mao your services to a special url pattern will auso help.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/service/**" access="ROLE_IP_AUTH" />
```

Comment: I added some additional clarifying information. I'm still a bit fuzzy in understanding how I segrgate the ROLE_IP_AUTH being authenticated in the BasicAuth filter from the ROLE_USER in the form filter, and how exactly spring will know which one to use if I don't define it somewhere.

Comment: You can add a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to add the role depending on the authentification or if you want to use the login but want to use different roles, you could use a custom `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` to change the role after the login based on the ServletPath.

Comment: @David Parks The answer by Philipp Hügelmeyer seems to be about providing access based on URL. See page #201 of Spring Receipe (2nd Ed) at http://books.google.com/books?id=IK2SMsT6XLYC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201. In that example, IP_LOCAL_HOST role is declared to invoke the Voter and it is not assigned to the user. Voter solution would work if you want to delegate decision to AccessDecionManager instead of assigning a new role to user. This approach might work for you and you can just grant ROLE_USER after doing a verification in a Voter.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh, that's a very helpful article. You should post that as an answer.