# Authenticating By IP Address In Spring 3.1: Smartest Way To Do That?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, ip

I've implemented LDAP authentication using Spring Security 3.1.  My security.xml file for that is posted below.

I need to alter my authentication process such that if a user comes to the site from an IP Address on a "white list" ( kept in a database table ), then that user should automatically be authenticated with Spring 3.1 and then redirected away from the login screen( not my idea, I was told to so).

If the user is not from one of the white listed IP Addresses, then s/he should be forced to go through the LDAP authentication on the login page.

I'm new to Spring and Spring Security so I went to the [Spring 3.1 Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html) and read all of Section I.  There, I read the advice that if you have any special authentication needs you should read  [Section II Architecture and Implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/overall-architecture.html).  I did that, very slowly and took notes.

However, since I am new to all of this I'm not sure I completely understand what I need to do and what is the smartest way of going about doing it.

---

**Update 3:  I got the skeleton code to work, here are the files I ended up with**

---

**My custom AuthenticationProvider implementation for authenticating by IP Address**

```
// Authentication Provider To Authenticate By IP Address With Allowed IPs
// Stored in a db table


package acme.com.controller.security;

//import acme.com.controller.security.CustomUserInfoHolder;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.NullAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider.class);
    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper = new NullAuthoritiesMapper();


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
    throws AuthenticationException {


        WebAuthenticationDetails wad = null;
        String userIPAddress         = null;
        boolean isAuthenticatedByIP  = false;

        // Get the IP address of the user tyring to use the site
        wad = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        userIPAddress = wad.getRemoteAddress();


        logger.debug("userIPAddress == " + userIPAddress);

        // Compare the user's IP Address with the IP address in the database
        // stored in the USERS_AUTHENTICATED_BY_IP table & joined to the
        // USERS tabe to make sure the IP Address has a current user
        //isAuthenticatedByIP =  someDataObject.hasIPAddress(userIPAddress);
        isAuthenticatedByIP = true;


        // Authenticated, the user's IP address matches one in the database
        if (isAuthenticatedByIP)
        {

            logger.debug("isAuthenticatedByIP is true, IP Addresses match");
            UserDetails user = null;


            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = null;

            result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("John Principal",
                                                              "PlaceholderPWE"); 

            result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

            return result;
        }


        // Authentication didn't happen, return null to signal that the 
        // AuthenticationManager should move on to the next Authentication provider
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication)
    {
        // copied it from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider
        return(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

}
```

**My *-security.xml file**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <s:http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>
    <s:http pattern="/search*" security="none"/>
    <s:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <s:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
    <s:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>




    <s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <s:form-login login-page="/login"
          authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </s:http>



    <s:ldap-server url = "ldap://ldap-itc.smen.acme.com:636/o=acme.com"/>


    <bean id="customIPAddressAuthenticationProvider" class="com.acme.controller.security.CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider" />


    <s:authentication-manager>
        <!-- Proposed: Custom Authentication Provider: Try To Authenticate BY IP Address First, IF NOT, Authenticate WiTh THE LDAP Authentication Provider -->
        <s:authentication-provider ref="customIPAddressAuthenticationProvider" />
        <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People"/>
    </s:authentication-manager>


</beans>
```

Comment: That's a really bad idea.  What if one of the white-listed addresses is that of a NAT firewall?  Then everybody behind that firewall (could be hundreds of people) will be automatically authenticated regardless of who they are.

Comment: That will not be happening in our situation and I've been ordered to do this.

Comment: You're probably going to have to experiment with the approaches you've already mentioned.  If the list of IP addresses doesn't have to change dynamically you could load them all at startup time.

Comment: Part of me would love to use a static list so I could use that handy hasIPAddress() function, but we really want to get things into a database.  I'm sure it will be the least of my worries, but I am wondering where among a custom AuthenticationProvider, Authentication, UserService I will be able to obtain an HTTPRequest obj so I can get the IP address to compare against a database list

Comment: @Steve Writing a provider class is the way to go. In the provider class's authenticate method, the authentication.getDetails(), by default, returns WebAuthenticationDetails(http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html). Its method getRemoteAddress will give you IP address.

Comment: also pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310147/spring-security-adding-a-new-role-which-supports-authentication-by-ip

Comment: Helpful Comment!  Thanks Ritesh!  I will check it out today and tomorrow.  THANKS!

Comment: Hi Guys.  Your comments have been very useful.  I thought about them, read more, tried some things, ended up having new questions.  If you aren't bored yet I would be grateful for any more guidance in getting to my goal.  Thanks.  Steve

Comment: @Steve It is looking good. Returning null is perfectly okay. The next provider in the chain will be consulted if you return null from authenticate method of your provider. Please see source code of LdapUserDetailsManager to see if you can use it to build UserDetails (method loadUserByUsername). You don't have to put ObjThatImplementsAuthentication in SecurityContextHolder in the provider class. Just make sure that ObjThatImplementsAuthentication that you are returning has everything that you need (principal, details and authorities).

Comment: <s:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" /> Add a bean as <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.acme.controller.security.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

Comment: I updated my original post in light of the comments.  I'm still having a problem.  Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-request-details-in-user-service

Comment: You might run into a problem if the application server is behind a reverse proxy and Spring Security does not attempt to query the request's "X-Forwarded-For" HTTP header to get the real source IP address.  In that case, you're right, it would be great to have access to the raw HttpServletRequest object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach seems pretty sound, you are right in thinking that Spring will try each AuthenticationProvider until it gets a successful result, so in your case you would define your IP based provider before the LDAP provider.

Depending on your setup you may not get a WebAuthenticationDetails object on your authentication.getDetails() call. If this is the case you should add Spring's [RequestContextListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/) or [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/) to your web.xml. You will then be able to get the source IP address by using the RequestContextHolder class and calling RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().

You should only need to implement an AuthenticationProvider, there is no need to implement a UserDetailsService, UserDetails or Authentication class. You should return null if you are not able to authenticate the user via his IP address. In this case Spring will try the LDAP provider. If for some reason you do not want to pass the attempt onto LDAP you should throw an AuthenticationException which will stop the process and ultimately result in a 403 error for the user.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I updated my original post in light of the comments.  I'm still having a problem.  Thanks in advance for any tips.