# IP filter using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

I wonder how to filter users' access to my web app by their IP using Spring Security.
Should I extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` or something like that and override it's methods in my own way?
If so, could you give an example of such extending and example of filter description in `web.xml`?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. In my app I also have Spring Security support (using default `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`), but I want it to check not only user credentials, but their IP's as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147161/authenticating-by-ip-address-in-spring-3-1-smartest-way-to-do-that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use Spring Security's [Web Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access-web).  For example:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
    ...
</http>
```

Comment: Worked great. Just make sure you've got use-expressions="true" as it is necessary for web security expressions to work. Although the solution does have that, it doesn't explicitly say that's necessary (which would have helped me ;)

Comment: This isn't a solution that would work well in real-world scenarios, however, since it's hard-coded into an XML file and requires an app-server restart.

Answer (score 1):

Anshu's answer is a good idea of authenticating a user by ip, but it may be not work with cas authentication. I have another resolution, using a filter is more suitable for this situation.

```
public class IPAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> authenticationUserDetailsService;
    private static Set<String> ipWhitelist;

    @Autowired
    private AppProperty appProperty;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ipWhitelist = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(appProperty.getIpWhitelist()));
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
    }

    public IPAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/");
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getHeader(appProperty.getHeaderCurUser());
        Assertion assertion = new AssertionImpl(userName);
        CasAssertionAuthenticationToken token = new CasAssertionAuthenticationToken(assertion, "");
        UserDetails userDetails = authenticationUserDetailsService.loadUserDetails(token);

        CasAuthenticationToken result = new CasAuthenticationToken(
                "an-id-for-ip-auth",
                userDetails,
                request.getRemoteAddr(),
                userDetails.getAuthorities(),
                userDetails,
                assertion
        );
        return result;
    }

    protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String userName = request.getHeader(appProperty.getHeaderCurUser());
        return ipWhitelist.contains(request.getRemoteAddr()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(userName);
    }

    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> getAuthenticationUserDetailsService() {
        return authenticationUserDetailsService;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(
            AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> authenticationUserDetailsService) {
        this.authenticationUserDetailsService = authenticationUserDetailsService;
    }
}
```

You can add this filter before cas like this:

```
http.addFilterBefore(ipAuthenticationFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
```