# spring security disable authentication ip based

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm writing an application which should use the authentication features of spring-security. The configuration is almost finished.

The problem: I don't know how to disable the authentication and -redirect for requests from localhost / ip-range.
We are using the Java Config for spring-security. There is the hasIpAddress function. But i don't think add this to each rules is the best solution.

Current configuration (nothing special):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/config/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            // ...
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()

            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // TODO: change to LDAP
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("testuser").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

}

Similar Topic:
[Authenticating By IP Address In Spring 3.1: Smartest Way To Do That?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147161/authenticating-by-ip-address-in-spring-3-1-smartest-way-to-do-that)
skips the authentication via ldap, but not the redirect, if I converted the config right

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786123/ip-filter-using-spring-security

Comment: Yes, the seconds one is similar to my reference.
The first one describes how to whit-list an ip(-range) for a plattern. My problem is not to allow the authentication. I don't want the redirect, too.